# Converting a list of pairs into smallest possible DataFrame representation?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, linear-algebra

I have a list of paired items and I'd like to convert them into a pandas DataFrame where each paired item shares the same number in the same columns. So something like this:

```py
[('A', 'B'),
('A', 'C'),
('B', 'D')]
```

is converted into...

```py
  0  1
A 2  1
B 3  1
C 2  0
D 3  0
```

So the columns are in decreasing order in number of pairs encoded, and it uses the fewest possible columns.

Is there an algorithm, preferably something in numpy or pandas, that does this? So far I've been unable to find anything with Google, but it's been a while since I had Linear Algebra, so I might have simply forgotten the right terms to use.

I created the following (buggy) code to create a DataFrame, but for some reason it creates as many columns as there are pairs and is not what I'd like to accomplish.

```py
def create_df(ps):
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.unique(ps))
    cnt = 1
    for p in ps:
        col = 0
        a, b = p
        while col in df.columns and (df.at[a, col] != 0 or df.at[b, col] != 0):
            col += 1
        df.loc[a, col] = cnt
        df.loc[b, col] = cnt
        cnt += 1
    return df
```

The ultimately goal of this is to integrate the output into a data pipeline so I can use groupby in pandas to calculate statistics over the pairs. Because of this, each pair must be defined in the same column, like in the example.

Comment: Could you add another example? Is not clear from your description what you want. Please include the comments in other answers as part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding code off-site that worked for me, here it is:

```py
def encode_pairs_info(pair_list):
    '''
    Encode the pair information in multiple columns group_i.

    Parameters
    ----------
    pair_list: list
    - Example:
        pair_list: [('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C')]
    Returns
    -------
    df: pd.DataFrame
    - Example:
            group_1 group_2
        A      1      0
        B      1      2
        C      0      2
    '''

    temp = pd.DataFrame(columns=['pair', 'pair_num', 'num', 'group'])

    for ipair in range(len(pair_list)):
        num_valid_1 = temp[temp.pair == pair_list[ipair][0]]
        num_valid_2 = temp[temp.pair == pair_list[ipair][1]]

        if num_valid_1.shape[0] == 0:
            num_temp_1 = [0]
        else:
            num_temp_1 = num_valid_1.num

        if num_valid_2.shape[0] == 0:
            num_temp_2 = [0]
        else:
            num_temp_2 = num_valid_2.num

        num_temp = min(set(range(1, ipair + 2, 1)) - set(num_temp_1) - set(num_temp_2))
        temp = temp.append({'ticker': pair_list[ipair][0],
                        'pair': ipair + 1,
                        'num': num_temp,
                        'group': 'group_' + str(num_temp)},
                       ignore_index = True)
        temp = temp.append({'pair': pair_list[ipair][1],
                        'pair_num': ipair + 1,
                        'num': num_temp,
                        'group': 'group_' + str(num_temp)},
                       ignore_index = True)

    df = pd.DataFrame(0,
                      index=temp.ticker.unique(),
                      columns=temp.group.unique())

    for irow in range(temp.shape[0]):
        df.loc[temp.ticker[irow]][temp.group[irow]] = temp.pair_num[irow]

    return df
```

With the input: `[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C')]` it results in:

```
    group_1 group_2 group_3
A   1   2   0
B   1   0   3
C   0   2   3
```

Answer (score 5):

This is more like a `pivot` problem after we do `melt`

```
s=pd.DataFrame(l).reset_index().melt('index')
s=s.assign(Col=s.groupby('value').cumcount()).pivot('value','Col','index').\
    add(1).fillna(0)
s
Out[62]: 
Col      0    1
value          
A      1.0  2.0
B      3.0  1.0
C      2.0  0.0
D      3.0  0.0
```

Comment: Your output differs from OP's example.

Comment: @crayxt my output is follow the logic of B 3.1 , if we want to match the A output with ops, we have inner conflict between the B and A

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work. I want to be able to groupby along columns, so each pair needs to be defined in the same column. The exact output doesn't need to be the same, but the 1.0's and 2.0's will need to be in the same column for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a numpy/scipy approach using a sparse matrix representation of the graph.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
from scipy import sparse
import pandas as pd

def rerepr_grph(g):
    vtx,edg = np.unique(g,return_inverse=True)
    npr,nvx = edg.size//2,vtx.size
    aux = sparse.csr_matrix(
        (np.ones(2*npr),edg,2*np.arange(npr+1)),(npr,nvx)).tocsc()
    deg = np.diff(aux.indptr)
    srt = (-deg).argsort(kind="stable")
    mxdg = deg[srt[0]]
    rlr = np.concatenate([aux.indices+1,np.zeros(mxdg,np.int32)])
    rlr = as_strided(rlr,(2*npr,mxdg),2*rlr.strides)
    szgrps = np.diff(deg.searchsorted(
        np.arange(mxdg+1),"right",sorter=srt[::-1]),axis=0)[::-1]
    triud = np.array([True,False]).repeat((mxdg,mxdg-1))
    triud = as_strided(triud,(mxdg,mxdg),2*triud.strides)
    msk = triud.repeat(szgrps,axis=0)
    res = np.where(msk,rlr[aux.indptr[srt]],0)
    return pd.DataFrame(res,index=vtx[srt])

def rerepr_pd(l):
    s=pd.DataFrame(l).reset_index().melt('index')
    s=s.assign(Col=s.groupby('value').cumcount()).pivot('value','Col','index').\
                    add(1).fillna(0)
    return s

data = [('A', 'B'),
        ('A', 'C'),
        ('B', 'D')]

print(rerepr_grph(data))
print(rerepr_pd(data))
```

Sample run (prints numpy and pandas (@WeNYoBen's code) answers to OP example:

```
   0  1
A  1  2
B  1  3
C  2  0
D  3  0
Col      0    1
value          
A      1.0  2.0
B      3.0  1.0
C      2.0  0.0
D      3.0  0.0
```

Speed comparison on large 1 million pair example:

```
# larger example

print()
print("creating larger (1,000,000 pairs) example",end=" ... ")

import itertools as it
from timeit import timeit
A,Z = np.uint32(ord("A")),np.uint32(ord("0"))
data = (np.stack(np.unravel_index(np.random.choice(2600**2,1_000_000,replace=False),(26,10,10,26,10,10)),axis=1).astype("u4") + (A,Z,Z,A,Z,Z)).view('U3')
print("done")
print("benchmarking")
print("numpy ",timeit(lambda:rerepr_grph(data),number=10)*100,"ms")
print("pandas",timeit(lambda:rerepr_pd(data),number=10)*100,"ms")
```

Sample run:

```
creating larger (1,000,000 pairs) example ... done
benchmarking
numpy  560.810615005903 ms
pandas 1843.7980080023408 ms
```

Comment: Sadly this won't work either. I want to be able to groupby along each column, so the pairs need to be defined in the same column. The numpy example is close though, I'll look into `as_strided` to see if that can solve my problem.

Comment: @RobRose What would your expected result be for [[A B] [B C] [C A]]? You can have it in the minimal number of columns, i.e. two or you can have the pairs in the same column. But not both at the same time.

Comment: They must be in the same column. The minimum number of columns with that constraint maintained. So I'd expect three columns for [[A B], [B C], [C A]].

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'D')])
```

First find all unique values in the dataframe:

```
>>> uniqs = list(pd.unique(df.values.ravel()))
>>> uniqs
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Next get a list (in reversed order) of indexes where these unique values occur, add them to a dict and build a dataframe from that dict:

```
dict = {}
for uniq in uniqs:
    dict[uniq] = list(reversed(df[df.eq(uniq).any(1)].index + 1))
dff = pd.DataFrame({key: pd.Series(value) for key, value in dict.items()}).T
```

Result:

```
>>> dff
     0    1
A  2.0  1.0
B  3.0  1.0
C  2.0  NaN
D  3.0  NaN
```

Comment: (or `dff.fillna(0)` if you want to avoid `NaN` entries)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a crazy solution, just for fun:

```
s = df.stack().reset_index(name='val')

s = (s.assign(level_1=s.duplicated(['level_1','val'])
                   .groupby(s['level_0'])
                   .transform('max')
                   .add(s['level_1']) % 2,
              level_0 = s.level_0 + 1
             )
      .pivot_table(index='val', 
                   columns='level_1', 
                   values='level_0',
                   fill_value=0)
      )

s.iloc[:,::-1] = np.sort(s, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
level_1  0  1
val          
A        2  1
B        3  1
C        2  0
D        3  0
```